SwiftUI GeometryReader returning 0.0 for ScrollView content size on initial render
I am trying to get the size of a ScrollView's content on the initial render of the View, but it is returning 0.0 instead of the actual size. I created a ChildSizeReader View following this post to try to achieve this, and the code looks like this:
ChildSizeReader:
struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var size: CGSize

    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content()
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
                    }
                )
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { sizeValue in
            size = sizeValue
        }
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGSize
    static var defaultValue: Value = .zero

    static func reduce(value _: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        _ = nextValue()
    }
}

Use of ChildSizeReader:
@State private var scrollViewSize: CGSize = .zero

...

ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        ChildSizeReader(size: $scrollViewSize) {
            FeatureSet(features: features)
        }
    }
}

FeatureSet:
struct FeatureSet: View {
    var features: [Feature]

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(Array(features.enumerated()), id: \.element.title) { index, feature in
                FeatureRow(title: feature.title, value: feature.value)
                    .id(feature.title)
                
                if index != features.count - 1 {
                    Divider()
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .overlay(Color(hex: 0x808080, opacity: 0.2))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I did also try wrapping Color.clear.preference in the conditional statement if proxy.size != .zero such as seen in this forum, but the size was still 0.0 when assigned to size.
But, the moment that I start scrolling, the size is set to the expected value.
Are there any ideas on how to retrieve the correct size of the ScrollView on the initial render? Thank you!

I would suggest simplifying your ChildSizeReader:

Use an .onChange handler to detect when the size of the GeometryProxy changes.

Supply initial: true to the .onChange handler, so that it also reads the size on initial show (this is the same as having an .onAppear callback doing the same thing).

A PreferenceKey is not needed.

The ZStack is not needed either.


struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var size: CGSize
    let content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content()
            .background {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .onChange(of: proxy.size, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
                            size = newVal
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}

An alternative way to implement the size reader is as a ViewModifier. I added a new answer to the post you referenced, to show how it can work this way.

Thank you for this simplification, it works exactly like the PreferenceKey method!

@YanivSagy Pleased to hear it works for you. I'm surprised that so many SO answers use a PreferenceKey for this sort of measuring purpose, because usually it can be avoided. Ps, you might like to consider accepting the answer (by tapping the checkmark), if it's the solution you chose to use ;)

The implementation of the preference key is incorrect. You never assigned anything to value in reduce, so it remains at the default value of .zero.
Here is a correct implementation:
struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGSize? = nil

    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize?, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        guard let next = nextValue() else { return }
        value = next
    }
}

Note that I changed the value of the preference to be optional, so as to satisfy the invariant documented here. Namely, reduce(value: &x, nextValue: {defaultValue}) does not change the meaning of x.
(Since Color.clear does not have any siblings, this is probably not necessary, but it's good to follow the documentation.)
In onPreferenceChange, unwrap the optional:
.onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { sizeValue in
    guard let sizeValue else { return }
    size = sizeValue
}


Apologies for taking a bit of time to respond, but thank you very much for the response. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have solved the issue on its own. I believe the main issue was that I was trying to use the scrollViewSize variable to update another state variable in the file where ChildSizeReader was being used, and then I was trying to use that state variable to modify the UI. However, this second state update was being completed before the ChildSizeReader re-ran after the initial render to calculate the correct ScrollView size, so I ended up using scrollViewSize directly.
